# Standard way to iterate over a StringBuilder in Java?

Tags: java, loops, iterator, stringbuilder

I was quite surprised that I couldn't find an existing questions answering this.

What is the standard way to iterate over all characters in a StringBuilder in Java?

The obvious route is to just convert it to a String then use toCharArray(). The problem is, I'm dealing with thousands of unique strings, with which I do a lot of appending, and I think I'm getting memory and performance issues from having to intern them all.

EDIT: to clarify, I'm not manually interning Strings, but my understanding was that they were automatically interned, and that if I called `toString` for a StringBuilder that they would be interned. Perhaps I have misunderstood.

Comment: StringBuilder does have a `charAt()` method. You could iterate over each character using that method.

Comment: What's this going to be like in terms of performance? Does charAt() provide O(1) access?

Comment: You are reading from an array, so yes. It will be O(1)

Comment: No. `StringBuilder` doesn't automatically *intern* Strings. How can you avoid something which you are not doing?

Comment: If you are so concerned about performance perhaps you could fold back a little and use byte[] or char[] instead depending how you are getting those "strings". How are you filling up the StringBuilder in the first place?

Comment: AFAIK The only strings that are internalized are string literals in the code and those Strings you call intern() on and perhaps some basic constants like "" otherwise they are not internalized at all.

Comment: I'm using a StringBuilder because I repeatedly append to the end of the strings. I'm implementing a very specific algorithm in formal language theory, so the operations I really need fast are concatenation and iterating through a string. I'm assuming char[] would cause problems if I don't always know the string size in advance?

Comment: @jmite I'm still curious to know what constructor or method you use to enclose a string into the StringBuilder. Obviously a custom byte[] or char[] solution would require you to hold the actual size of the string there in in a separate variable and resize the array when there is not enough capacity... I guess that at the end of the day that is what StringBuilder does for you and the only thing you would save is method call overhead which is not terrible. Yet the way you add the string into the string builder is what is key here.

Comment: Perhaps you could post a code sniplet

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First off, if you're interning lots of strings, you're doing something very wrong.

More generally, `StringBuilder` implements `CharSequence`, just like `String`. Use an ordinary counter-based `for` loop and `charAt()`.

Comment: 1. How do I avoid interning strings? I'm using a StringBuilder for nearly everything I do, avoiding strings wherever I can. Can you expand on the "something very very wrong" and how to avoid it?  2. Does charAt() give O(1) access?

Comment: @jmite 1. you aren't interning anything when using a Builder.  Infact, nothing is interned from a built String unless you explicitly call `intern()` on the built String. But you haven't even created a String object yet, you can do all of this directly from the mutable Builder. 2. Yes `charAt()` does give O(1) access to the underlying array

Comment: Okay. I knew that StringBuilders weren't interned, which is why I was using them. I was concerned they would be interned if I used `toString`. I'll use charAt instead and see how it works. Thanks!